# How can I record from my microphone input?

Tags: 11.10, sound, microphone

I have an audio input plugged into my mic jack.  In `alsamixer`, when I unmute and     amplify the `mic` input, I can hear this audio out of my speakers.  However, running `arecord -d 5 foo.wav` and `aplay foo.wav` results in an empty file; the same when recording through audacity - empty.

Why does this happen?  How do I record this input?

`arecord -L` produces the following, if this is helpful:

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
pulse
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
front:CARD=nForce2,DEV=0
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=nForce2,DEV=0
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=nForce2,DEV=0
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=nForce2,DEV=0
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=nForce2,DEV=0
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=nForce2,DEV=0
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=nForce2,DEV=0
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=nForce2,DEV=1
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2 - MIC ADC
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=nForce2,DEV=0
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=nForce2,DEV=1
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2 - MIC ADC
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=nForce2,DEV=0
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=nForce2,DEV=1
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2 - MIC ADC
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=nForce2,DEV=0
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=nForce2,DEV=1
    NVidia nForce2, NVidia nForce2 - MIC ADC
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Changes made on the `Input` tab of the `System Settings -> Sound` dialog make no difference at all.  No sound comes out of my speakers because of them, and Audacity records nothing as a result of changing any setting (either the connector or the input volume).  There is only one "device for sound input" - the `Internal Audio Analog Stereo`.

Oddly, in Audacity, changing the recording source (say from `default:Line:0` to `default:Mic:0`, or even `Mono` to `Stereo`) sets the `mute` checkbox on the aforementioned dialog.

Comment: Are you sure you are using pulseaudio? Does using the `Sound Recorder` app work?

Comment: No, `Sound Recorder` behaves the same way - nothing recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem using the guide [Recording audio playing on the computer](https://web.archive.org/web/20111107021136/http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Recording_audio_playing_on_the_computer). Enable the capture devices in alsamixer. I still have no idea how to solve this using the graphical interface.

Comment: The link is dead, which is why link-only answers are not very useful!

Answer (score 2):

You can record from the default input device.

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i default output.wav
```

Here is the [reference](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#pulse)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to select the proper device. Try something like `arecord -d 5 -D plughw foo.wav`. You can list all valid device names with `arecord -L`.

Comment: I tried all devices except for `surround*` (most of which it gave me some sort of error for), but none worked.  See my edited question for my list of devices.

Answer (score 1):

Open 'System Settings' > 'Sound' > 'Input', select your device and now record what you want. Audacity is recommended for that.

Comment: This seems to have no effect.  See my edit.

Comment: I had a problem like your, and it was all about changing BIOS and System Settings configurations.